# From javascript for loop to underscore each

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an Angular app where I am looping through a collection. I am using a classic for loop, but for like to use something more up to date. underscore.js is already included in the project, and I took a look at using _.each

This is my current (working) js code:

```
Batches.create($scope.newPanel).then(function(panel) {
        console.log('panel created: ' + panel.id);
        for(i = 0; i < $scope.selector.tabledata.length; i++){
            createPanelDetails(panel.id, $scope.selector.tabledata[i]);
        }
```

I would like to use the _.each, but how do I pass in the **panel.id** variable as I do with the for loop?

```
_.each($scope.selector.tabledata, createPanelDetails(panel.id ??, iterator???);
```

Or should I be using some other method from underscore to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an inline function:

```
_.each($scope.selector.tabledata, function(data) {
    createPanelDetails(panel.id, data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

via underscore

```
_.each($scope.selector.tabledata, function(elem) {
  createPanelDetails(panel.id, elem);
});
```

via angular

```
angular.forEach($scope.selector.tabledata, function(elem, i){
  createPanelDetails(panel.id, elem);
});
```

I recommend to follow refrigerator's advice to use angular for consistency.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this using bind to create a partial function

Underscore:

```
_.each($scope.selector.tabledata, _.bind(createPanelDetails, undefined, panel.id));
```

Angular:

```
angular.forEach($scope.selector.tabledata, angular.bind(undefined, createPanelDetails, panel.id));
```

Comment: What is the meaning of "undefined" in these functions?

Comment: @ardochhigh sets `this` in the bound function to `undefined`, good thing to point out because if that function is in the scope of an object and the function uses `this` to refer to that object then the object should be passed instead of `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use case for [`_.each`](http://underscorejs.org/#each) and [`_.partial`](http://underscorejs.org/#partial).

```
_.each($scope.selector.tabledata, _.partial(createPanelDetails, panel.id));
```